# Using ternary search tree for predictive text

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I am trying to write a program, that when a user starts typing a word in a search bar, the program will display a list of words that the user might be trying to type.

I have a dictionary with about 400k words. Currently I am trying to store everything in a TST and work with that data structure. What I am having trouble with, is the fact TST use keys. I was able to write a terrenary search tree that uses keys and values, and it seems to work, but I have no clue what I should use for keys for my program. Or is there maybe a better/easier data structure I can use for this program? I am trying not to use a lot of memory.

This is so far what I have for the Node class and insert.

```
private Node root;
    private class Node
    {
        char c;
        Node left, mid, right;
        Value val;
    }

public void put(String key, Value val)
    {
        root = put(root, key, val, 0);
    }

    private Node put(Node x, String key, Value val, int d)
    {
        char c = key.charAt(d);
        if(x== null)
        {
            x = new Node();
            x.c = c;
        }
        if(c < x.c)
            x.left = put(x.left, key, val, d);
        else if( c > x.c)
            x.right = put(x.right, key, val , d);
        else if (d < key.length () -1)
            x.mid = put(x.mid, key, val, d+1);
        else
            x.val = val;
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like your keys are your strings, and you don't have anything to use as the *values*?

Comment: Yes, I am not really sure what to use for values. I am thinking of just, cutting that part out, and just sticking with keys. I should get the same result right?

Answer (score 0):

As for a beter datastructure, you should consider using a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It's also known as a prefix tree, which is a more fitting name in this context. A possible way of implementing this can be found [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2070706).

Comment: I used a Trie originally. But a Trie uses up a ton of memory, and for my project I run out of memory. A TST is supposed to be basically a Trie but uses less memory.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you don't need a key. Can you show me a reference.  I also use TST for example for fast pattern matching.